# Sending excel file as a attachment in sql

Tags: sql, excel, email-attachments

I am facing issue while sending sql data as a excel attachment in an email.I have a output data in sql as 08-5643 but while the data comes in excel as a attachment it shows up Aug-43.

I tried adding sql data with double quotes something like "08-5643" but it is the same issue while the data comes in Excel.

I tried casting the SQL data into text format but still the same issue.

Comment: Is it possible for you to export the data with a leading apostrophe like so `'08-5643` (casted as text again)?

Comment: How do you convert the sql data to an excel file? CSV? Copy+Paste? What Tools/Scripts are you using?

Comment: I am using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail command and using @query parameter to specify the data